# What is a name someone would describe a false homophobe?

Tags: slang

What would you call a person who calls another person a "faggot" in a very hateful way, when this other person is not a homosexual.

Comment: Konrad, I think it's very unlikely that there is a word for a situation as complicated as that. What names have you come across in your research, that we might start to consider?

Comment: An ill-informed person(in a derogatory sense). Most people are ill-informed that way,  because most of them use 'faggot' as a substitute for 'stupid'. It's now just a slang-term.

Comment: @Margana: well, none. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many derogatory terms - such as "faggot" - are not used based on their literal or slang meaning. Instead, some people use these words as a general insult.

Anecdotally speaking, I have a homosexual friend who calls others "faggot". Obviously he's not using it to mock gay people, but the word has been overused in some environments (such as online gaming) that it has largely lost its meaning.

---

Therefore you're looking for a word to describe a person who makes a general hateful insult to another person.

I believe the slang word you're looking for to describe this person is:

> An **asshole**